# How to store array of really huge numbers in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, int, factorial

I am working with huge numbers, such as 150!. To calculate the result is not a problem, by example
`f = factorial(150)` is
`57133839564458545904789328652610540031895535786011264182548375833179829124845398393126574488675311145377107878746854204162666250198684504466355949195922066574942592095735778929325357290444962472405416790722118445437122269675520000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

But I also need to store an array with N of those huge numbers, in full presison. A list of python can store it, but it is slow. A numpy array is fast, but can not handle the full precision, wich is required for some operations I perform later, and as I have tested, a number in scientific notation (float) does not produce the accurate result.

Edit:

150! is just an example of huge number, it does not mean I am working only with factorials. Also, the full set of numbers (NOT always a result of factorial) change over time, and I need to do the actualization and reevaluation of a function for wich those numbers are a parameter, and yes, full precision is required.

Comment: Why would you expect it not to be slow? That's likely just a trade-off you'll have to make. What are you doing with all of these factorials, anyway?

Comment: Staring with a list, I know you said it slow but what is your use case? How are you using the data? Iterating it or getting items by index or making sublists? Maybe you can use a dict and group the data in some way? I suspect it's not the data you are storing so much as how much data you have. I expect it'd be just as slow (give or take) if you were storing smaller numbers...

Comment: Do you actually need exact factorial values?  There are approximations that are _much_ faster to calculate. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation  Also, `numpy` arrays aren't inherently faster, they're mostly just more compact in memory.  (Mathematical operations on the whole array are fast, but indexing is slow compared to a `list`.)

Comment: FrankV is right, context is important in making data structure choices - maybe give us some insight into your use case?

Comment: It is likely not the storage itself that is slow, but the operations you're performing with those huge numbers. The bigger the integer, the slower the math.

Comment: Can you list the operations which you'll perform on the numbers, give the order of magnitude estimate on the numbers and an estimate of how many of them you need to have stored at any one time?

Comment: Mark, yes, my operations are the main impact in performance, and depending of the data structure, they can be even slower (like 25% more), so I am looking for the better way to store values.

Joe Kington, the problem is not calculation, it is storage, and yes, i need full precision. If I would use something like 6.321324345e+23 the result of my calculations wil be wrong.

Comment: Dmitry Rubanovich: The bigger number to be stored is something like 200!, there will be between 20 - 60 numbers (this one does not change while running). My operations are sometimes divisions, sometimes sums, sometimes rest or multiplications, or a convination of them.
As far as I have tested, a numpy array can not hold numbers as large as mine without lost precision. A python list can, but to access a list is slower, so, there is another way?

Answer (score 4):

numpy arrays are very fast when they can internally work with a simple data type that can be directly manipulated by the processor. Since there is no simple, native data type that can store huge numbers, they are converted to a float. numpy can be told to work with Python objects but then it will be slower.

Here are some times on my computer. First the setup.

`a` is a Python list containing the first 50 factorials. `b` is a numpy array with all the values converted to `float64`. `c` is a numpy array storing Python objects.

```
import numpy as np
import math
a=[math.factorial(n) for n in range(50)]
b=np.array(a, dtype=np.float64)
c=np.array(a, dtype=np.object)

a[30]
265252859812191058636308480000000L

b[30]
2.6525285981219107e+32

c[30]
265252859812191058636308480000000L
```

Now to measure indexing.

```
%timeit a[30]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 34.9 ns per loop

%timeit b[30]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 111 ns per loop

%timeit c[30]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 51.4 ns per loop
```

Indexing into a Python list is fastest, followed by extracting a Python object from a numpy array, and slowest is extracting a 64-bit float from an optimized numpy array.

Now let's measure multiplying each element by 2.

```
%timeit [n*2 for n in a]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.73 µs per loop

%timeit b*2
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.76 µs per loop

%timeit c*2
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.24 µs per loop
```

Since `b*2` can take advantage of numpy's optimized array, it is the fastest. The Python list takes second place. And a numpy array using Python objects is the slowest.

At least with the tests I ran, indexing into a Python list doesn't seem slow. What is slow for you?

Comment: He wants to ensure that integer arithmetic is used.  To the best of my knowledge, you can't can't make that guarantee with Numpy.  It will start loosing precision and converting to floating point with exponent if the numbers get too large.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich  If you tell numpy to use `dtype=np.object`, it will keep the value as a Python long and you won't lose precision. However, you won't gain any of the performance that numpy can offer when it uses native types. Compare the values of `b[30]` and `c[30]` in my examples. `c[30]` is kept at full precision but `b[30]` is converted to a float.

Answer (score 0):

If you need for the future the exact number of a factorial why dont you save in an array not the result but the number you want to 'factorialize'?

E.G.

You have `f = factorial(150)`

and you have the result `57133839564458545904789328652610540031895535786011264182548375833179829124845398393126574488675311145377107878746854204162666250198684504466355949195922066574942592095735778929325357290444962472405416790722118445437122269675520000000000000000000000000000000000000`

But you can simply:

```
def values():

    to_factorial_list = []
        ...
        to_factorial_list.append(values_you_want_to_factorialize)
    return to_factorial_list

def setToFactorial(number):
    return factorial(number)

print setToFactorial(values()[302])
```

EDIT:

fair, then my advice is to work both with the logic i suggested as the `getsizeof(number)` you can merge or work with two arrays, an array to save low factorialized numbers and another to save the big ones, e.g. when `getsizeof(number)` exceed any size.

Comment: I am not always with x!. Just some huge numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Store it as tuples of prime factors and their powers.  A factorization of a factorial (of, let's say, N) will contain ALL primes less than N.  So k'th place in each tuple will be k'th prime.  And you'll want to keep a separate list of all the primes you've found.  You can easily store factorials as high as a few hundred thousand in this notation.  If you really need the digits, you can easily restore them from this (just ignore the power of 5 and subtract the power of 5 from the power of 2 when you multiply the factors to get the factorial... cause 5*2=10).

Comment: My problem is not to get the factorials, is to store them in a structure that can handle their full precision and be as fast as possible to iterate throw. For example, iteration over a list is slower than over a numpy array, but a numpy array lost the presicions.

Comment: iterate over what?  there is only 150 factorials for numbers 1-150.  If each factorial is stored as a tuple (rather than a number), you can iterate over the list of these stored tuples.  You can even have a dictionary from the N to the tuple (which stores the prime powers of N!).

Comment: Iterating over a structure (array, list or something) of huge numbers (not always results of x!) stored in full precision.